# How to make clicking on div redirects to anchored point at another page

Tags: javascript, html

Example single service 1st tag redirects to #xx and 2nd one redirects to #yy both on another subpage of my website.

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
            <div class="single-service lk1">
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing eli</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
            <div class="single-service lk2">
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing eli</p>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>

const $offert = ["xx", "yy"];
const $clicken = $('.single-service');

$($clicken).click(function(){
        window.location='oferta/index.html';
    })});
```

Comment: Welcome on stackoverflow, Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)..

Comment: Maybe you want to do this : window.location='oferta/index.html#anchorName';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
            <div class="single-service lk1" data-anchor="xx">
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing eli</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
            <div class="single-service lk2" data-anchor="yy">
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing eli</p>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>

const $clicken = $('.single-service');

$($clicken).click(function(){
        window.location='oferta/index.html#'+$(this).data('anchor');
    })});
```

Comment: Oh thanks ! It works exacly what i was looking for, good that i've asked cause i've tried to make it harder that it was ! :D

Answer (score 1):

**These things are meant to work without script engine assistance**

Please use the conventional HTML Anchors, such as `<A ID="sectionID"` and utilize fractal URL's on a link such as `<A HREF="oferta/index.html#sectionID"..` to make a Hyper-Jump.

Comment: I was not sure if i can make this jump, as i said i've complicated easy task. Thanks anyway, i've checked and it worked but it made my element a link so i think i will stay in this function solution (i know i can get rid of it easily) but do you think it will have any impact at my site ? Slower loading or sth ?

Comment: Oh :) In case you ever wondered why is there an H in the name of HTML this is exactly why! The the Anchor and the Link. It was the A Tag that revolutionized the WWW long before JavaScript muscle was deployed. **The use of A Tag is no longer mandatory because we now (since W3C 1996 at least ) we have ID standard *attribute* which can be applied on any HTML Element**

Answer (score 0):

just add # and id of a div you want to go to ie.

```
window.location='oferta/index.html#id';
```

Comment: My main problem with that solution is that i would have to write almost same line of code 6 times for each element in my row that it can redirect to each another anchor. I want to modify it a little so in 1 function i can somehow count which one was clicked and redirect to the anchor it matches

Comment: store anchors in id and use `window.location='oferta/index.html#' + this.id;`

Comment: This would work only if my id of div that i want to click was the same as element i want to redirect to. Am i right ?

Comment: Patryk Brudzyński yes